# Failing accessibility audit when a ol element has a role

Tags: html, google-chrome, accessibility, audit

When you do an Accessibility Audit in Google Chrome with sites like https://stackoverflow.com you will notice an error I'm having with my own website.

```
List items (<li>) are not contained within <ul> or <ol> parent elements.
```

In the case of https://stackoverflow.com the HTML with the error looks like this.

```
<ol class="list-reset grid gs4" role="presentation">
                <li class="grid--cell">
                ...
```

When I had this error with my website I removed the role attribute and the error went away.

I have one simple question. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> List items (`<li>`) are not contained within `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent elements.

This error message is not explicit.

Implicit role for `ol` and `ul` elements is `list`. Implicit role for `li` elements is `listitem`.

[The ARIA documents says:](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#listitem)

> Authors MUST ensure elements with role `listitem` are contained in, or owned by, an element with the role `list` or `group`.

If you're overriding native role of `ol` elements, then you no longer respect the ARIA specs (while still respecting HTML specs).

Just remove the `presentation` role on the `ol` element or do not use list elements.

Comment: I get it my confusion came from the lack of understanding from the role attribute. Thank you for clear that up

Comment: Yes, roles don't cascade, so if you want the list to be purely for presentation, you need to put `role="presentation"` on the list and the list items.